# Java EE 7 tutorial, netbeans can't find glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

The instructions for the Java EE tutorial specify to download and install the following :

Java SE SDK
Java EE SDK
Netbeans

I downloaded SE 8, EE 7 & Netbeans 8.0.2

Installed SE ok, and EE ok - it's essentially glassfish4. While installing Netbeans I'm instructed in the tutorial to NOT install glassfish and, when done with Netbeans to add glassfish to the Netbeans installation.

When I do so, I get the following message (I'm pointing @ c:\glassfish4\glassfish which is the correct path AFAIK)

**Not a valid GlassFish Server installation.**

I've seen another person in the last week with this same error, I looked into that problem and it said that there should be a file in a directory to solve the problem (C:\glassfish4\glassfish\config\glassfish.container).  That file does exist on my system.

How does netbeans determine a valid Glassfish installation?

**ETA: I followed zapl's advice below, reinstalled Netbeans with it's default Glassfish and, when I right click on Glassfish 4.1 Server, all options are greyed except Refresh and Remove (so, no start/stop, no view of Admin Console, Server Log or Update Center)**

Comment: why don't you use a bundle that has an installer for everything: https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html ? (I guess that means DO install glassfish where your tutorial says no).

Comment: @zapl - because the tutorial says not to do that :)

Comment: When you add a server I think the path you want is `c:\glassfish4`. This is the root directory of the application server and contains the `bin` directory. I just checked my NetBeans and both my GlassFish instances are added that way.

Comment: @matt - same error.  there is a `bin` directory there but no luck.

Comment: I can only guess that you haven't installed GlassFish correctly. When you say you skip that step in the NetBeans installer, and then 'add it afterwards', are you actually installing GlassFish 4 and then adding it to NetBeans? Or is there just a GlassFish directory created during the NetBeans install? Maybe install a fresh GlassFish and try adding that? You can get it here: https://glassfish.java.net/download.html

Comment: @matt - I presume from reading your questions that you haven't done this and are just guessing? These are the instructions from oracle to install the jee tutorial. The glassfish from netbeans is not installed at all by unticking a box during installation as per the instructions. There is no way to install glassfish incorrectly, it's extracted from a zip file downloaded from oracle.com.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Usually when I install NetBeans I get the EE bundle and let it install GlassFish for me, however I also use older versions of GlassFish and I install those myself, as you say, by downloading the zip file and extracting it, and then adding it as a server in NetBeans by pointing at the /glassfish4 or /glassfish3 directory. So my comment is based on the procedure I follow.

Comment: @matt - thanks for clarifying, it's very puzzling why this doesn't work - I would expect many queries if this was a common failure.  If I could figure out why netbeans didn't consider my glassfish installations valid I could (maybe) figure out how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. It is a known Netbeans-Bug: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=253008

There appear to be two solutions:

1. Use a nightly Build Netbeans Version equal or higher than 201506180001
2. In /glassfish/lib/install/applications/__admingui/WEB-INF/lib link (or copy) console-core-4.2-SNAPSHOT.jar to console-core-4.1.jar. After that netbeans is able to find the JAR file and add Glassfish nightly as a Glassfish 4.1 server.

I renamed the JAR as in solution 2 and now it works fine...

Hope this helps!

Comment: The SNAPSHOT file doesn't exist and the 'non'-SNAPSHOT file does exist. I see my 8.0.2 is 20141118......  I will try to find a later build

Comment: Fixed - download last nights build - live dangerously, right :)

Comment: i am going through same problem so what i have to do